no queue data inserted in jobs table laravel
hello guys I have a form where user can select multiple images and uploading them all when he submits the form , each image's size is 1 or 2mb ,the request take too long time (pending) due to image's size.. I have decided to use queue for making uploading images process in background but I don't know does not work ..
if image size aren't big they're uploading .. but if image's size is big it takes long time then request responds with 201 all data that I have submitted excluding images have inserted in database but there're not images inside images tables.. and my main question is noth jobs inserted in jobs or failed table why??
this is TripController
    public function create(TripRequest $tripRequest)
    {
        $validatedData = $tripRequest->validated();

        // Create the trip with basic details
        $trip = Trip::create([
            'title' => $validatedData['title'],
            'description' => $validatedData['description'],
            'trip_type' => $validatedData['trip_type'],
            'address' => $validatedData['address'],
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        ]);


        // Prepare the image data for the job
        $imagesData = array_map(function ($imageData) {
            return base64_encode(file_get_contents($imageData->getRealPath()));
        }, $validatedData['images']);

        // Dispatch the job
        UploadImagesProcess::dispatch($trip->id, $imagesData);

        return new JsonResponse($trip, JsonResponse::HTTP_CREATED);
    }

and this is UploadImages job
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\Trip;
use App\Models\Image;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UploadImagesProcess implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public function __construct(public $tripId, public $imagesData)
    {
    }

    public function handle(): void
    {
        //New 
        $trip = Trip::find($this->tripId);

        if ($trip) {
            foreach ($this->imagesData as $imageData) {

                $decodedImage = base64_decode($imageData);


                $filename = uniqid() . '.webp';


                $filePath = '/images/trips/' . $filename;
                Storage::put('public/' . $filePath, $decodedImage);


                $image = new Image([
                    'image_url' => $filePath,
                    'image_for' => 'trip',
                ]);


                $trip->images()->save($image);
            }
        }
    }
}


the configuration
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
database
I know that I should leave php artisan queue:work command working .. but it's not the reason for not inserting anything in jobs table...

I think you should ensure that our queue worker is running properly. While you mentioned that you know the php artisan queue:work command should be running, it's crucial to double-check that it's indeed active. Sometimes, if the queue worker encounters errors, it might stop running without any visible indication. Running php artisan queue:work in your terminal and keeping an eye on its output for any error messages can help diagnose this.
Since you're using the database queue connection, ensure that your database connection settings are correctly configured in your .env file. Make sure that Laravel can connect to your database without any issues.
Ensure that your queue.php configuration file (usually found in the config directory) is set up correctly. Specifically, check that your database queue configuration matches your environment.
If these don't work, then you can consider wrapping your job's logic in a try-catch block and logging any exceptions that occur within the job.
